# How to jump back to NERDTree from file in tab?

Tags: vim, ide, nerdtree

I usually:

1. Choose the needed file.
2. Open it in a tab(t character, by default).

But how I can jump back to NERDTree to open one more file in a tab?

Temporary solution I use now in my .vimrc file:

```
map <F10> :NERDTree /path/to/root/of/my/project
```

But it's not very useful to start navigation again and again from the root directory.

Comment: I don't understand your update. No, the NERDTree isn't displayed in its own tab, but when you open a new file in a new tab, you should be able to use `gt` to jump back to the tab containing NERDTree?

Answer (score 755, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>

This will move between open windows (so you could hop between the NERDTree window, the file you are editing and the help window, for example... just hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and press <kbd>w</kbd> twice).

Comment: >>just hold down "control" and press "w" twice. Unfortunately, I don't see anything changed after this.. And there's nothing special im my vimrc for this shortcut. Do you have any ideas? Please help

Comment: Ctrl-ww will move the cursor between the split windows of the active tab. In a brand-new tab, there are not splits and thus ctrl-ww will do nothing.

Comment: As might your assumption of my guess, Manni.

Comment: I think this answer is better!

Comment: What if I push W three times?

Comment: We search for this answer :)

Comment: Excellent answer +1. But Is it documented in the NERDTree documentation? Actually I didn't find it out.

Comment: I'll be honest, I have no idea where I originally learned this. I probably found it worked in some other plugin and just gave it a shot (or even just fiddled around with pressing various key combinations to see what would happen and discovered it by accident... I don't recall)

Comment: It should be in the NERDTree doc... Actually this is not a NERDTree command but a basic Vim command.

Comment: If you don't want to cycle through the windows just use `1 ctrl-ww` to jump to the first windows which is NT

Answer (score 223):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> cycle though all windows

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> takes you left a window

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> takes you down a window

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> takes you up a window

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> takes you right a window

Answer (score 102):

NERDTree opens up in another window.  That split view you're seeing?  They're called windows in vim parlance.  All the window commands start with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd>.  To move from adjacent windows that are left and right of one another, you can change focus to the window to the left of your current window with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>h</kbd>, and move focus to the right with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>l</kbd>.  Likewise, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>k</kbd> will move you between horizontally split windows (i.e., one window is above the other).  There's a lot more you can do with windows as described [here.](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html)

You can also use the :NERDTreeToggle command to make your tree open and close.  I usually bind that do t.

Comment: it helps a lot to put a :NERDTreeToggle keybinding in your .vimrc.  I use <F4>, but that's just me.  I put project.vim, taglist, and NERDTree on <F2>, <F3>, and <F4>, respectively.  Now it's easy to get around my projects.  That works really poorly with MiniBufExplorer though, so if you use that you may have some issues.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. For some reason, it is not too obvious to a novice user that the NERDTree actually opens a new Vim window. Once I understood that, and learned a few commands to navigate windows, I not only started using NERDTree effectively, but Vim windows became a convenient way to open multiple files in the same screen!

Answer (score 80):

If you use <kbd>T</kbd> instead of <kbd>t</kbd> there is no need to jump back because the new tab will be opened, but vim's focus will simply remain within NERDTree.

Comment: What if we are using buffers instead of tabs (as one is often told to do with Vim)? *edit: answer below is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 31):

You can focus on a split window using `# ctrl-ww`.

for example, pressing:

```
1 ctrl-ww
```

would focus on the first window, usually being NERDTree.

Comment: press ctrl after 1 is indeed a long journey.

Answer (score 17):

Since it's not mentioned and it's really helpful:

<kbd>ctrl-w</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>

which I memorize as *go to the previously selected window*.

It works as a *there and back* command. After having opened a new file from the tree in a new window press <kbd>ctrl-w</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> to **switch back** to the NERDTree and use it again **to return** to your previous window.

PS: it is worth to mention that <kbd>ctrl-w</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> is actually documented as *go to the preview window* (see: `:help preview-window` and `:help ctrl-w`).

It is also the only keystroke which works to switch inside and explore the [COC](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) [preview documentation window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZrdz.png).

Answer (score 9):

<kbd>ctrl-ww</kbd> Could be useful when you have limited tabs open. But could get annoying when you have too many tabs open.

I type in `:NERDTree` again to get the focus back on NERDTree tab instantly wherever my cursor's focus is. Hope that helps

Answer (score 6):

The top answers here mention using <kbd>T</kbd> to open a file in a new tab *silently*, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> to hop back to nerd-tree window after file is opened normally.

IF WORKING WITH BUFFERS: use <kbd>go</kbd> to open a file in a new *buffer*, *silently*, meaning your focus will remain on nerd-tree.

Use this to open multiple files fast :)

Comment: `ctrl+ww` was what I was looking for

Answer (score 5):

You can change the tabs by <kbd>ctrl-pgup</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl-pgdown</kbd>. On that tab you came from the NERDTree is still selected and you can open another tab.

Answer (score 5):

In more recent versions of NERDTree you can use the command `:NERDTreeFocus`, which will move focus to the NERDTree window.

Answer (score 2):

`gt` = next Tap
`gT` = previous Tab

Answer (score 2):

if you want you can enable the mouse support editing ~/.vimrc file.

put `set mouse=a`

after that you enable files click in NERDTree.

Answer (score 0):

All The Shortcuts And Functionality is At

`press CTRL-?`